# Put tick mark on the button corner

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to tick mark on my button on the right corner. I set the input value to  it gives me a buttoner text with tick mark I wanted to it should be placed on the right corner.

```css
.buttoner{
            background-color: #4CAF50;
              border: none;
              cursor: pointer;
              height: 48px;
              border-radius: 5px;
              width: 10%;
        }
```

```html
     <input type="button" class="buttoner" value="buttoner&#10003"/></input>
```

i want like this:

[image: I want like this]

Comment: pls add some example.. html css

Comment: Please show your code or atleast an example of what you want?

Comment: done.you can check my post now.

Comment: Can i modify the html code?

Comment: Do u want the tick mark form green box right top corner?

Comment: yes. same as that image I attached

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```css
.my-btn {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}
.buttoner {
background-color: #66bb6a;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
height: 48px;
border-radius: 3px;
width: 120px;
text-align: center;
color: white;
line-height: 48px;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
}
.my-btn .fa-check {
position: absolute;
top: 5px;
right: 10px;
color: #fff;
font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Button with tick mark</title>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="my-btn">
<input type="button" class="buttoner" value="Button"/>
<i class="fa fa-check"></i> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Button with tick mark</title>
 <style type="text/css">
    .buttoner{
          background-color: #4CAF50;
          border: none;
          cursor: pointer;
          padding:12px 30px;
          display:inline-block;
          border-radius: 5px;
          color:#fff;
    }
    .tick{
      display:inline-block;
      position:relative;
    }
    .tick:after{
            content: '';
            position:absolute;
            right:11px;
            top:8px;
            display: block;
            width: 5px;
            height: 9px;
            border: solid #fff;
            border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
            transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<span class="tick"> <input type="button" class="buttoner" value="button"/></input></span>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this i added..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Button with tick mark</title>
     <style type="text/css">
        .button_box{
              background-color: #4CAF50;
              border: none;
              cursor: pointer;
              height: 48px;
              border-radius: 5px;
              width: 10%;
              position: relative;
        }
        .buttoner {
            background-color: transparent;
            border: none;
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .button_box span {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
        }
     </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="button_box">
    <input type="button" class="buttoner" value="buttoner"/>
    <span>&#10003</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```